# Python Instagram API - API requests fail

Tags: python, python-2.7, instagram

I am learning how to use the Instagram API through python-instagram package.
I have setup the Clients, have Client ID and Client Secret. I have gotten an Access Token using the get_access_token.py script in python-instagram, but for some reason I am always getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-6440f86cbefd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/PythonProjects/minefield/instagram test.py', wdir='F:/PythonProjects/minefield')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "F:/PythonProjects/minefield/instagram test.py", line 13, in <module>
    api.user_search(q='samsungmobile')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\bind.py", line 196, in _call
    return method.execute()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\bind.py", line 182, in execute
    include_secret=self.include_secret)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 224, in prepare_request
    url = self._full_url_with_params(path, params, include_secret)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 148, in _full_url_with_params
    self._full_query_with_params(params) +

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 144, in _full_url
    self._signed_request(path, {}, include_signed_request, include_secret))

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 172, in _signed_request
    return "&sig=%s" % self._generate_sig(path, params, self.api.client_secret)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 127, in _generate_sig
    return  hmac.new(secret, sig, sha256).hexdigest()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\hmac.py", line 136, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\hmac.py", line 71, in __init__
    if len(key) > blocksize:

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

and here is my code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = '1********4.0*****5.fb1c**********39***7365*********'
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
api.user_search(q='samsungmobile')
```

The script fails when calling the last line api.user_search(q='samsungmobile')
I have no idea how this TypeError got raised, but I suspect it may have something to do with the access token.

I am certain I am using the correct one. The get_access_token.py script returns a tuple of length 2, the first index contains the access token as a string, the second index contains a dictionary containing user info about who is authorized to use the app.

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem. you need to use the latest version of the code for oauth2.py, which is in github. in particular, see this changelist:

https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/commit/d46e0eb96dcf5a3aad687da4081b91441b3392e5

in particular, this is the old and new line in oauth2.py:

```
-        if include_signed_request:
+        if include_signed_request and self.api.client_secret is not None:
```

everything works after that change.